# Prove that $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[53]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=8$. Prove that:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[53]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}$$
I think $uvw$ does not help here.

My another similar inequality is very easy:

with the same condition prove that:
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[27]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}}$$
My proof:

By AM-GM $(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+24\geq9\sqrt[9]{(a^3+b^3+c^3)\cdot3^8}$

and we are done!

Thank you!

Comment: What is $u v w$?

Comment: See here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: @Wei-Cheng Liu It's mine.

Comment: Continuing with the inequality that you already proved, it suffices to show 
$
\sqrt[27]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}} \geq \sqrt[53]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}}
$ and, after using the extra condition,  a 2-d plot shows that this actually holds true.

Comment: I think your inequality is wrong. Try $a=b$ and $c=0$.

Comment: Well, $a=b$ and $c=0$ gives, with the condition, $a=b=4^{1/3}$, and one has to show  $\sqrt[27]{\frac{8}{3}} \geq \sqrt[53]{\frac{2 \cdot 4^{4/3}}{3}}$ which is $1.0370 \geq 1.0276$ so this is fine.

Comment: By the way, your proof of the second inequality appeared earlier (July 2013) in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435969/

Comment: Yes, @Andreas , my counterexample is not good. It seems that your inequality is true, but we need to prove it. My proof of the second inequality you can see also here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h106225p945097 (October 2007)

Comment: I set up a question. Let's get some inspiration from the community.

Comment: @Andreas I proved it by BW. It's 18-th degree only.

Comment: Michael: I deliberately set up the question as the 54th root (in here) to get ideas from the community which one may generalize. I guess you cannot, with reasonable effort, use BW here with the 53rd root....

Comment: No, it does not work. We'll get a very big degree.

Answer (score 2):

(Homogenization)We need to prove that (for $a, b, c \ge 0$, at most one of them is zero)
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b+c}{3} \ge \sqrt[53]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3}\Big(\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{8}\Big)^{49/3}}.
\end{align}
WLOG, assume that $c=1$ and $a+b \ge 1$. Let $p=a+b, \ q = ab$. Using $a^4+b^4 = p^4-4p^2q+2q^2$, taking logarithm on both sides, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
f(p, q) = 53\ln \frac{p+1}{3} - \ln \frac{p^4-4p^2q+2q^2+1}{3}
- \frac{49}{3}\ln p - \frac{49}{3}\ln (1+p+q) + \frac{49}{3}\ln 8 \ge 0.
\end{align}
Since $q \le \frac{p^2}{4}$ and $p\ge 1$, we have
$52p^2-3p-3-55q \ge 52p^2-3p-3-55(\frac{p^2}{4}) = \frac{153}{4}p^2-3p-3 > 0$. Thus, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}
&= -\frac{2(52p^2-3p-3-55q)^2
- 2713\, p^4 - 36\, p^3 - 54\, p^2 - 36\, p + 2677}{165(p^4-4p^2q+2q^2+1)(1+p+q)}\\
&\le -\frac{2(\frac{153}{4}p^2-3p-3)^2
- 2713\, p^4 - 36\, p^3 - 54\, p^2 - 36\, p + 2677}{165(p^4-4p^2q+2q^2+1)(1+p+q)}\\
&= -\frac{31p^4-72p^3-72p^2+392}{24(p^4-4p^2q+2q^2+1)(1+p+q)}\\
&\le 0.
\end{align}
Thus, we have $f(p, q) \ge f(p, \frac{p^2}{4})$. It suffices to prove that $f(p, \frac{p^2}{4})\ge 0$ or
$$g(p) = 53\ln \frac{p+1}{3} - \ln \frac{p^4+8}{24}
- \frac{49}{3}\ln p - \frac{49}{3}\ln (1+p+\frac{p^2}{4}) + \frac{49}{3}\ln 8\ge 0.$$
Note that $$g'(p) = \frac{(p-2)(37\, p^4 - 48\, p^3 - 96\, p^2 - 96\, p + 392)}{3(2+p)(p+1)(p^4+8)p}.$$
Since $37\, p^4 - 48\, p^3 - 96\, p^2 - 96\, p + 392 > 0$, we have $g'(p) < 0$ for $1\le p < 2$ and $g'(p) > 0$ for $2 < p$. Thus, $g(p) \ge g(2) = 0.$ We are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! But this idea does not work always. It's better to say that it hardly ever works.

Comment: I agree. By the way, the KKT conditions (or Lagrange multiplier) can also be used easily to get the result that two of $a, b, c$ are equal.

Comment: Can you show? I tried to use LM, but without success. The system turns out very ugly. Also, why for equality case of two variables we'll get unique minimum points?

Comment: If you prove that two of them are equal using any method,  WLOG, assume that $a=b$, you may obtain $c = \frac{2-a\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}}$ from $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=8$. Let $a = u^2$ and $c = \frac{2-u^3}{u}$. Then prove $f(u) = \ln \frac{a+b+c}{3} - \frac{1}{53}\ln \frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3} \ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using KKT conditions (or Lagrange multiplier)

Let
\begin{align}
L = \ln \frac{a+b+c}{3} - \frac{1}{53}\ln \frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{3} 
- t ((a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - 8).
\end{align}
From $\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial c} = 0$, we have
\begin{align}
0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial b}= 
\frac{\left(a - b\right)\, \left((53a^5+53a^4b+53ab^4+53ac^4+53b^5+53bc^4)t-4a^2-4ab-4b^2\right)}{53(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)},\quad \cdots\cdots\cdots (2)\\
0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial b} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial c}
= \frac{\left(b - c\right)\, \left((53a^4b+53a^4c+53b^5+53b^4c+53bc^4+53c^5)t-4b^2-4bc-4c^2\right)}{53(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)}. \quad \cdots\cdots\cdots(3)
\end{align}
We claim that two of $a, b, c$ are equal. Otherwise, from (2), we have
$$t= \frac{4(a^2+ab+b^2)}{53(a^5 + a^4\, b + a\, b^4 + a\, c^4 + b^5 + b\, c^4)}$$
which, when inserted into (3), results in
$$\frac{4}{53}\frac{\left(a - c\right)\, \left(b-c\right)\, \left(a\, b + a\, c + b\, c\right)}{\left(a + b\right)\, \left(a^4 + b^4 + c^4\right)} =0.$$
Contradiction.

Further we claim that $a = b = c$. Otherwise, WLOG, assume that $a = b \ne c$, from (3), we have
$$t = \frac{4}{53}\frac{a^2 + a\, c + c^2}{2\, a^5 + 2\, a^4\, c + a\, c^4 + c^5}$$
which results in
$$0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = -\frac{1}{53}\frac{ - 74\, a^4 + 48\, a^3\, c + 48\, a^2\, c^2 + 24\, a\, c^3 - 49\, c^4}{\left(2\, a^4 + c^4\right)\, \left(2\, a + c\right)}.$$
However, $- 74\, a^4 + 48\, a^3\, c + 48\, a^2\, c^2 + 24\, a\, c^3 - 49\, c^4\ne 0$
which follows from $74x^4-48x^3-48x^2-24x+49  > 0$ for all real numbers $x$. Contradiction. We are done.